# Parse.Cloud.beforeSave not working / Parse-Server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am almost done migrating an Objective-C iOS app from Parse.com to a self-hosted Parse-Server.
But while doing some checking, I noticed that my cloud function `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave` is not executed, or at least not doing all its job. **Why is that?**

The collection(MyCollection) I want to add a record to is updated as expected, but I have a second collection (for book keeping) that I update (to keep the number of the last inserted item) on the way and that is not done.

For reference, here is the function code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave
("MyCollection", function(request, response)
 {
 var queryConfig;

 var queryConfig = new Parse.Query("BooKeep");
 queryConfig.find({
                  success: function(resultConf) {
                  request.object.set("..", resultConf[0].get("...")+1); // This is done as expected.
                  resultConf[0].set("...", resultConf[0].get("...")+1); // Not done!
                  request.object.set("...", resultConf[0].get("...")+1); // This is done as expected.
                  resultConf[0].set("....", resultConf[0].get("...")+1); // Not done!
                  resultConf[0].save(null,{}); // Not done!
                  ....
                  response.success();
                  },
                  error: function() {
                  var reptMsg="The BooKeep-UPDATE procedure failed for some reason.";
                  console.log(reptMsg);
                  response.error(reptMsg);
                  }
                  });
  });
```

A bit more investigation further down the road, shows the following in the logs. At least now I know that Parse.Cloud.beforeSave is run, which I was  not quite sure before.

```
 app[web.1]: info: beforeSave triggered for MyCollection for user Yacb6CzuB9:
 app[web.1]:   Input: {....}
 app[web.1]:   Result: {"object":{....}} className=MyCollection, triggerType=beforeSave, user=Yacb6CzuB9
 app[web.1]: error: Error generating response. { [Error: unauthorized: master key is required] status: 403, message: 'unauthorized: master key is required' } status=403, message=unauthorized: master key is required
 app[web.1]: Error: unauthorized: master key is required
 app[web.1]:     at promiseEnforceMasterKeyAccess (/app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/middlewares.js:297:17)
 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/PromiseRouter.js:137:22
 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
 app[web.1]: error: Error generating response. ParseError {
 app[web.1]:   code: 119,
 app[web.1]:   message: 'Permission denied for action update on class BooKeep.' } code=119, message=Permission denied for action update on class BooKeep.
 app[web.1]: [object Object]
 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/BooKeep/JKKmaSzi8H" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=1348711c-25df-4f6e-005b-70632776742d fwd="54.90.99.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=34ms status=400 bytes=573
2016-11-25T02:47:58.488404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/logout" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=dc3b12d1-5f54-11f0-a8cd-54ceca331a80 fwd="106.130.44.123" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=483
```

Comment: which version of parse server are you using?

Comment: How can I check that? I got it only a few days ago, I guess it's the latest.

Comment: The Parse Command Line Interface I was running was Version 3.0.2. I just ran parse update and I am now using Version 3.0.5. I am not sure it is related to my issue though.

Comment: I edited my post to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to make it work by going to the _SCHEMA collection and changing:

```
    "update": {
        "Yacb6CzuB9": true
    },
```

to:

```
    "update": {
        "*": true,
        "Yacb6CzuB9": true
    },
```

for the class BooKeep.

I still don't quite get why I have to do that, because I don't need everyone to have update rights, but the fact is that it now works.
I'd be happy if someone could comment and indicate a better solution.